# What's the function of the comma in this piece of code?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand this code with the method.each_with_object.
I do not understand how the comma (after `units[name]`) works inside the block.

More clearly, what is its function? 
Why there is a comma that separates the `units[name]` from `seconds=...` and it is not written as `units[name, seconds=seconds....]`?

This is the piece of code:

```rb
units = durations.each_with_object({}) do |(name, duration), units|
    units[name], seconds = seconds.divmod(duration)
end.reject { |k, v| v.zero? }.map(&singularize)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `.map(&singularize)` is not really relevant to the question, so I've lopped that off.

**Sample data**

Let's break down this code snippet. For that we need some data. I'm guessing that `durations` may look something like the following, but the actual structure is probably not important.

```
seconds = 1630
durations = [["Bob", 3600], ["Melba", 60]]
```

Bob consumes time in hours; Melba, in minutes.

**The enumerator**

We begin by defining an enumerator.

```
enum = durations.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"Bob"=>3600, "Melba"=>60}:each_with_object({})>
```

**First value generated by `enum`**

The first element is generated by `enum` and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values.

```
(name, duration), units = enum.next
  #=> [["Bob", 3600], {}] 
name
  #=> "Bob" 
duration
  #=> 3600 
units
  #=> {}
```

**Array decomposition**

The process of breaking down `enum.next` is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). That link deserves a careful read. In fact, the entire file is well-written and informative. Notice how the parentheses in `|(name, duration), units|` correspond to the brackets in the array `duration`. See also [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

**Block calculation**

The block calculation can now be performed.

```
units[name], seconds = seconds.divmod(duration)
  #=> units["Bob"], seconds = 1630.divmod(3600)
  #=> units["Bob"], seconds = [0, 1600]
units
  #=> {"Bob"=>0} 
seconds
  #=> 1630
```

Once again, we have used array decomposition. As `duration` equals the number of seconds per hour for Bob (3600), `units["Bob"]` is set equal to a number of hours he "consumed" and `seconds` now equals the remaining number of seconds remaining. As the latter is unchanged (`1630`), we infer that Bob can only consume time in multiples of hours, so he consumed zero seconds.

**Second value generated by `enum`**

After the block informs `enum` that it is ready for another element to be generated, we have the following.

```
(name, duration), units = enum.next
  #=> [["Melba", 60], {"Bob"=>1}] 
name
  #=> "Melba" 
duration
  #=> 60 
units
  #=> {"Bob"=>0}
```

Notice that `units` has been updated. Continuing,

```
units[name], seconds = seconds.divmod(duration)
  #=> units["Melba"], seconds = 1630.divmod(60)
  #=> units["Melba"], seconds = [27, 10]
units
  #=> {"Bob"=>0, "Melba"=>27}
seconds
  #=> 10
```

We see that Melba has consumed `27` minutes worth of the `1630` seconds, leaving `10` seconds.

**The block asks for the next element from `enum`**

The block is now ready for another element from `enum`.

```
(name, duration), units = enum.next    
   #=> #StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

`enum` has raised a `StopInteration` exception as it has no more elements to give. This causes the value of `units` (`{"Bob"=>0, "Melba"=>27}`) to be returned by the block.

**Remove non-consumers of time**

Lastly, we rid ourselves of everyone who consumed zero seconds.

```
{"Bob"=>0, "Melba"=>27}.reject { |k, v| v.zero? }
  #=> {"Melba"=>27}
```

**More complex examples of array decomposition**

Here are two.

```
arr = [[1, {a:2}, [3, [4, 5..6]]], 7]

(a, b, (c, (d, e))), f  = arr
a #=> 1 
b #=> {:a=>2} 
c #=> 3 
d #=> 4 
e #=> 5..6 
f #=> 7

[arr].each do |(a,b,(c,(d,e))),f|
  puts a
  puts b
  puts c
  puts d
  puts e
  puts f
end
1
{:a=>2}
3
4
5..6
7
```

Again, compare the locations of the parentheses with those of the brackets in `arr`.

The use of array decomposition is extremely useful, but seems to be underutilised.

Comment: Hello Cary
Many thanks for your time and the very complete explanation. 
I have saved some of the links you suggested.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby you can "deconstruct" an array and bind it to multiple variables in the following manner `a, b = [1, 2]`, where `1` will be bound to `a` and `2` to `b`. To give an example:

```
[1] pry(main)> a, b = [1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
[2] pry(main)> a
=> 1
[3] pry(main)> b
=> 2
```

Knowing this the above code is the same as

```rb
units = durations.each_with_object({}) do |(name, duration), units|
    result = seconds.divmod(duration)
    units[name] = result.first
    seconds = result.last
    result
end.reject { |k, v| v.zero? }.map(&singularize)
```

To reflect upon your question `units[name, seconds=seconds....]` is not valid Ruby. A Hash's `[]` method expects only one argument. You could define your own class that accepts more.

```
# The following was tested on ruby 2.6

class A
  def [](name, surname)
    puts "#{name} #{surname}"
  end

  def []=(name, surname, value)
    puts "#{name} #{surname} = #{value}"
  end
end

a = A.new
a['foo', 'bar'] # prints 'foo bar'
a['foo', 'bar'] = 'baz' # prints 'foo bar = bar'
```

So you could define your own Hash implementation that does what you described, but by default it doesn't.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment it has been very helpful in understanding the syntax in Ruby. Thanks